# How do I convert variable of type DWORD or char* to LPCWSTR?

Tags: c++, winapi, msdn

Given a message:

```
char *appStrt = "Application has already been started in a different window.";
```

I am trying to use it in the following function:

```
MessageBox(NULL, appStrt, // (LPCTSTR) appStrt cast doesn't work here
           appRun,
           MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK);
```

how can I convert appStrt to LPCSTR so MessageBox doesn't complain?
I have the same problem in the following peice of code:

```
DWORD dwStyle;
m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(dwStyleEx,
                    m_pszClassName,
            dwStyle | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, // complains here about dwStyle
            0,
                        etc.
```

CreateWindowEx is also throwing an error stating that dwStyle should be of type LPCWSTR.
I searched online but only found conversions such as:
LPCWSTR newWord = L"OldWord"
but I need something that would convert a variable of type DWORD or char* to LPCWSTR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TCHAR` instead of `char`:

```
TCHAR appStrt[] = _T("Application has already been started in a different window.");
```

As for your second problem, you might want to check [a reference of `CreateWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as you are missing an argument in the call before the styles.

Comment: it says "_T" is undefined, thanks for the answer on the second problem, that worked.

Comment: @YuriSwarovski You might want to [read this on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks, I am new to MSDN winapi programming so this doc will help.

Comment: `_T()` is used for the C runtime, not the Win32 API, that is why `_T()` is defined in the C runtime's `tchar.h` header file to begin with. The Win32 API defines its own `TEXT()` macro that does the same thing that `_T()` does.  Use `_T()` for C code and `TEXT()` for Win32 code: `TCHAR appStrt[] = TEXT("Application has already been started in a different window.");`

Answer (score 2):

There's no simple conversion, just start with the right thing in the first place

```
TCHAR *appStrt = _T("Application has already been started in a different window.");
```

For the second example you've got your parameters in the wrong order. For CreateWindowEx the third parameter is the window title, the fourth parameter is the window style. You've put the window style where the window title should go.

As a general principle, don't take compiler error messages too literally. If the compiler says cannot convert xxx to yyy, it doesn't *always* mean that you do need to convert xxx to yyy. Both these examples illustrate that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MessageBoxA()` instead, then you do not have to convert your `char*` data (especially useful if the data is dynamically allocated at runtime instead of statically like in your example - otherwise, use `MultiByteToWideChar()` and then call `MessageBoxW()`).

As for `CreateWindowEx()`, you are passing your window style value in the `lpWindowName` parameter instead of the `dwStyle` parameter, that is why the compiler is complaining about `LPCWSTR`.